# angularjs how to nest ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

In angularjs how should the JSON data be and how should the nesting of ng-repeat be to get the data as shown in figure ?
[image]

Comment: please post what you have now . also what you have tried so far.

Comment: code and fiddle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>


<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

    <div class="container">

        <table class="table">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>
                        <table class="table">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>Sample</th>
                                    <th>sequence</th>
                                    <th>attribute</th>
                                    <th>MeasureUnit</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                        </table>
                    </th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr ng-repeat="record in records">
                    <td>
                        <table class="table">
                            <thead>

                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                <tr ng-repeat="record in record.data">
                                    <td>{{record.sample}}</td>
                                    <td>{{record.sequence}}</td>
                                    <td>{{record.attribute}}</td>
                                    <td>{{record.MeasureUnit}}</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr ng-if(record.data.length= =index+1)>
                                    <td><button class="btn btn-danger">Delete Sample {{record.sample}}</button></td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>

        <script>
            var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
            app.controller("myCtrl", function ($scope) {
                $scope.records = [
                  {
                      sample: 1,
                      data: [{ sample: 1, sequence: 1, attribute: 'Height', MeasureUnit: 'centimeter' },
                          { sample: 1, sequence: 2, attribute: 'Height', MeasureUnit: 'centimeter' }, ]
                  },
                  {
                      sample: 2,
                      data: [{ sample: 2, sequence: 1, attribute: 'Height', MeasureUnit: 'centimeter' },
                          { sample: 2, sequence: 2, attribute: 'Height', MeasureUnit: 'centimeter' }, ]
                  },
                ]
            });
        </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for a great answer

Answer (score 0):

You can use groupBy filter:

No need to make data nested, just add a column you want to group by like below example:

```
$scope.players = [
  {name: 'Gene', team: 'alpha'},
  {name: 'George', team: 'beta'},
  {name: 'Steve', team: 'gamma'},
  {name: 'Paula', team: 'beta'},
  {name: 'Scruath', team: 'gamma'}
];
```

[jsbin](http://jsbin.com/weyov/45/edit?html,js,output)

Answer (score 0):

This JSON format might help you,

```
    [
    {sample :1, 
        data: [{sample:1,sequence:1,attribute:'Height',MeasureUnit:'centimeter'},
            {sample:1,sequence:2,attribute:'Height',MeasureUnit:'centimeter'},]
    },
    {sample:2,
        data:[{sample:2,sequence:1,attribute:'Height',MeasureUnit:'centimeter'},
            {sample:2,sequence:2,attribute:'Height',MeasureUnit:'centimeter'},]
    },
]
```